# arc length of the polar curve $r^2= \sin2\theta$

Tags: polar-coordinates

given curve is $r^2 = \sin2\theta $

I got $L= \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{r^2+ ({\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}})^2}\ d\theta$ = $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{r^2}} d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{\sin2\theta}} d\theta  = 2\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{1 \over \sin2\theta} d\theta$ (by the polar graph)

but for 2$\int_0^{\pi \over 2} \sqrt{1 \over \sin2\theta} d\theta$, i don't have any idea to proceed

Comment: have you tried the substitution $u = \tan(\theta)?$

Comment: i haven't, but could you give any hint with u=tan(θ)?

Comment: Are you supposed to know elliptic integrals ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arc length = $4I = 4\int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt{1 \over \sin 2 \theta}\ d\theta.$ make a change of variable $u = \tan \theta, du = (1+u^2) d\theta.$

$$I = \int_0^{\pi/4} \sqrt{1 \over \sin 2 \theta} \ d \theta 
 = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1+u^2 \over 2u} \ {du \over 1 + u^2}
 = {1 \over \sqrt 2} \int_0^1 {1 \over \sqrt{u(1+u^2)}} \ du$$

i will have to think about how to proceed from here.

Comment: Did you get rid of the elliptic integral ?

Comment: hmm. i thought it could be expressed by elementary funcitons but failed. my instructor presented this problem but maybe he couldn't consider about this.

Comment: @fbg, this is elliptic integral. i don't think it can be expressed in terms elementary functions.